According to premillennialism, will people on Earth be able to have a cup of coffee with Jesus during the millennium?
Edit: The question refers only to the literal millennium view!
Some background of my question: I have watched videos by some exegetes, who claim Jesus will never go out of the Temple in Jerusalem during His reign of 1000 years, once He has defeated all His enemies at the beginning. Some of the exegetes even claim Jesus will be visible only in form of Shekhinah in the Temple. So I am wondering if all this is true. I would really prefer if we’d be able to have a cup of coffee in a local café during a conversation with Jesus. The following Bible verse gives me some hope:
Matthew 26:29

I tell you, I will not drink from this fruit of the vine from now on until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father’s kingdom.

Could we else infer from the Scriptures what it will be like in the 1000 years kingdom in terms of (personal) interaction with Jesus?

Lds say no to coffee

I edited the question! @ Kris: I only drink decaf :)

I think the answer is Yes.
Christ ate and drank with the Apostles post-resurrection as has been discussed elsewhere, so if the question is "will we be able to sit and have a cup of Coffee with Jesus", the answer would be yes.
Luke 24:42-43

They gave him a piece of broiled fish, 43 and he ate it as they watched.

We also know life will be, at least in some ways, very similar to how it is now. For example, Isaiah 65:21

And they shall build houses, and inhabit them; and they shall plant vineyards, and eat the fruit of them.

As far as our personal interactions with him, he will likely be much like he was when he was on earth, so his interactions with others as they were in the Bible - talking, eating, and drinking - are going to be similar, as he doesn't change.
Hebrews 13:8

Jesus Christ is the same yesterday, today, and forever.

Interestingly, and worth mentioning, Latter-day Saints have additional scripture which specifically details what life will be like in the resurrection (D&C 130:1-2), which reads:

When the Savior shall appear we shall see him as he is. We shall see
that he is a man like ourselves.
And that same sociality which exists among us here will exist among
us there, only it will be coupled with eternal glory, which glory we
do not now enjoy.

